# Why my water level indicator outputs low to microcontroller even after disconnecting the positive +5V?

Tags: circuit-design

The problem occurs only if leads are kept immersed in water. [image]

Comment: how do you know that the output is low?

Comment: The 330k resistors look like they might be intended to be pull-ups, but they are not connected to the supply? What value are the capacitors? and how long are the wires to the tank?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks. Don't know how I missed to put supply to the pull-ups. The caps are 0.1u. Wire length ~30 feet.

Comment: @jsotola 1) Microcontroller is doing its job when the pin is pulled low
               2) Checked with multimeter

Comment: @Pritam then, please edit your question and fix the circuit schematic so that the things are pulled up.

Comment: If you measure the DC and AC voltage (that is two measurements) between the right-hand "+5V" electrode (when otherwise open, not connected to +5V) and circuit GND, what do you see?